# How should line rules be used?

Tags: discussion, formatting

The [guidelines for good answers](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/684/what-guidelines-help-make-an-answer-good) (or its experimental [variant formatting of much the same content](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/694/what-makes-a-good-answer)) should probably include some guidance on the use of line rules.

I think they would best be used for separating less critical content when using a header would provide excessive emphasis. However, it could be argued that line rules could be used for separating sections of a text when a header would be excessively disruptive or when only one header would be required in the post.

What advice should be given concerning the use of line rules in answers (and perhaps in questions)?

Comment: I don't think there's a hard-and-fast guideline for this. I don't think we particularly need one. The line break is rarely used (and, IMHO, for good reason), and on the other hand, it doesn't have much abuse potential. Prettifying our site up is nice, but addressing line breaks feels like a very minor detail that just doesn't feel constructive to me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see myself using rules, since I can do almost the same thing with headers, which are more [SEO friendly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) and work better for blind people and screen readers. A line rule is nothing for such kind of software and, in my opinion, shouldn't be used at all.

Besides, I don't think a header would give excessive emphasis, since it just 
separates contexts inside an answer.

Less critical content supports the conclusion and doesn't need to be separate in such a drastic way. Instead, you can bold or empathize the parts of the text you really think are important. That would clearly make sure the reader gets what you want.

So, like I said, rules exist and there's no point in ruling that they should not be used but, in the same way, I don't think they should be advised what would inevitable happen in case we create best practices rules.

Just leave them be. If somebody really thinks it's necessary to use rules, ok. In general, we can just try not to use them.